# How to evaluate column values in two *ngFor arrays in angular

Tags: angular

I am working in an angular app ,  the goal is to evaluate if a user has a subscription for the listed service (which is an array).

```
  servicesList = [
    {
      name: "medical",
    },
    {
      name: "security",
    },
    {
      name: "roadside",
    },
  ];
```

I want to do  a comparison with what the user has subscribed on then show a `UNLINK` button if there is a subscription for that service else show `LINK`

THe Subscription data is as follows

```
  subscriptions = [
    {
      service: "medical",
      company_id: "32563
    },
    {
      name: "security",
      company_id: "25801"
    }
  ];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to build upon the answer that Vamsi shared. You can create a find function that will let you know if a user is subscribed or not and then you can use that function in your *ngIf.

```
isUserSubscribed(title: string): boolean {
    return this.subscriptions.findIndex(sub => sub.service === title) > -1;
}
```

Then, in your HTMl you can use *ngIf as follows:

```
<button *ngIf="!isUserSubscribed('medical')">Link</button>
<button *ngIf="isUserSubscribed('medical')">Unlink</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a find function and use *ngIf

```
isUserSubscribed(sub: string) {
return this.subscriptions.find(x => x.subscriptions == sub);
}
```

in HTMl use *ngIf

```
<button *ngIf="!isUserSubscribed('medical')" >Link</button>
<button *ngIf="isUserSubscribed('medical')" >Unlink</button>
```

Change the argument according to the option you want to validate.

Comment: There is a minor problem with your isUserSubscribed() function. Array.find() returns the first element of the array according to the given condition while your return type is boolean. You'll have to do a comparison against undefined to return a boolean.

Comment: yes you are correct, removed return type now this should be good

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the assist.

I did try the solution and for reason its running the function multiple times and even before running the function that gets the subscription data from the localstorage.

This is the code I have

```
  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.storage.get("subscriptions").then((data) => {
      console.log('User Subs:',data);
        if (data == "") {
          this.noSubs = true;
        } else {
          this.subscriptions = data; //?
          this.noSubs = false;
        }
    });
  }

  isUserSubscribed(title: string): any {
    console.log("Searching.....", title, " Subscriptions Found:", this.subscriptions);
    if (!this.noSubs && this.subscriptions !== undefined) {
      console.log("Subs Exists");
      const data =  this.subscriptions.findIndex((subscription) => subscription.service == title) > -1;
      console.log('Found Data', data);
      return data;
    } else {
      console.log("No Subs Found");
      return (this.isSubscribed = false);
    }
  }
```

This is the output on console.

[image: ```]

It seems to be working since its showing the expected results on the UI, but I just want to make sure that its running correctly and these console logs seems to point that there is a problem.

[image]

Comment: That is expected to happen. You can do something like this at the root of your html template to ensure it only gets run once the user subscriptions are there. <div *ngIf="this.soSubs"></div>